# How to specify username/password in Java Metro?

Tags: java, java-metro-framework

I'm trying to create a Web Service Client with Metro that uses WS-Security.

I have used Axis2, and to specify the username/password in an Axis2 client, I do:

```
org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient sc = stub._getServiceClient();
org.apache.axis2.client.Options options = sc.getOptions();
options.setUserName("USERNAME");
options.setPassword("PASSWORD");
```

How do I provide a username/password in a Metro client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to auth using basic http headers:

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "WSHttpBinding_ICustomerService")
public ICustomerService getWSHttpBindingICustomerService() {
    WebServiceFeature wsAddressing = new AddressingFeature(true);

    ICustomerService service =
        super.getPort(new QName("http://xmlns.example.com/services/Customer",
                "WSHttpBinding_ICustomerService"), ICustomerService.class, 
                wsAddressing);

    Map<String, Object> context = ((BindingProvider)service).getRequestContext();

    Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    headers.put("Username", Collections.singletonList("yourusername"));
    headers.put("Password", Collections.singletonList("yourpassword"));

    return service;
}
```

If the service uses `NTLM` (Windows authentication) (explanation [here](http://biemond.blogspot.com/2009/04/jax-ws-web-service-proxy-client-and.html)):

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "WSHttpBinding_ICustomerService")
public ICustomerService getWSHttpBindingICustomerService() {
    WebServiceFeature wsAddressing = new AddressingFeature(true);

    ICustomerService service =
        super.getPort(new QName("http://xmlns.example.com/services/Customer",
                "WSHttpBinding_ICustomerService"), ICustomerService.class, 
                wsAddressing);

    NtlmAuthenticator auth = new NtlmAuthenticator(username, password);  
    Authenticator.setDefault(auth);   

    return service;
}
```

Haven't used this myself, but seen other use it:

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "WSHttpBinding_ICustomerService")
public ICustomerService getWSHttpBindingICustomerService() {
    WebServiceFeature wsAddressing = new AddressingFeature(true);

    ICustomerService service =
        super.getPort(new QName("http://xmlns.example.com/services/Customer",
                "WSHttpBinding_ICustomerService"), ICustomerService.class, 
                wsAddressing);

    Map<String, Object> context = ((BindingProvider)service).getRequestContext();

    context.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "yourusername");
    context.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "yourpassword");

    return service;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The variable headers in your first example is set but not used. There's something missing.